# How to set a required protobuf field to its default value?

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

In protobuf 2 / C++, how do you set a required message field to its default value?

Comment: Documentation..?

Comment: I've read the documentation but I haven't found the answer. Maybe it's me... Could you point it out?

Comment: Looks like the first Google result for "protobuf default value" has what you need...

Comment: My first google result is https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto . It does talk about default values for optional fields, but not required. I don't find your comments very helpful. Why can't you just tell me the answer if you know it?

Comment: I don't need to because somebody already did. Still, you should use the documentation as your first port of call. Prior research is required. Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `Clear` method to reset the field to default value:

```
message Msg {
    required int32 i = 1 [default = 10];
};

Msg msg;
msg.set_i(123);

msg.Clear(); // Set the field to default value: 10.

// Another way:
msg.clear_i();
```

However, this will make the required field cleared, i.e. `msg.has_i() == false`. If you want to make it being set, also do the following:

```
msg.Clear();
msg.set_i(msg.i());
```